# Just updated to Android 4.2.2, Facebook Messenger doesn't push notifications now?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, facebook-messenger

I just updated my Samsung Galaxy S3 (model SCH-I535) to Android version 4.4.2. It seems fine, except for one bug I've noticed recently.

Facebook messenger will not always give me a notification that a message has been received. I've got it set to flash the light and show the icon on the top task bar only, but here is what I have determined:

- If messenger is currently open while the phone is locked or the screen is off, no notification is pushed.
- If messenger is off screen but still running while the phone is locked or off, some of the time it pushes a notification, and sometimes it does not.
- Mostly I notice a small (1) next to the messenger icon, but no light notification.

Is this just a new feature? I have tried everything I can think of with the settings, uninstalling and reinstalling, clearing the cache and stored data for messenger, and I'm out of ideas.

Does anyone know what this could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that Facebook Messenger has updated overnight, and I do not notice this issue anymore. Sorry for jumping the gun!